# Python regex using re. to remove some combinations

Tags: python, regex

In a file I have methods defined as follow.

```
@Override
PROCEDURE Prepare___ (
   attr_ IN OUT VARCHAR2 )
IS
  ----
BEGIN
   --
END Prepare___;

PROCEDURE Insert___ (
   attr_ IN OUT VARCHAR2 )
IS
  ----
BEGIN
   --
END Insert___;
```

Some of the are overridden and some are not.

Right now i'm using the following regex to find the procedures and functions.(this works fine)

```
r"^\s*((FUNCTION|PROCEDURE)\s+(\w+))(.*?)BEGIN(.*?)^END\s*(\w+);"
```

But here I want to drop the functions and procedures which has @Override annotation.

How can I modify the existing regex to do that. Or should I use a new way to do this.

this is my code

```
methodRegex = r"^\s*((FUNCTION|PROCEDURE)\s+(\w+))(.*?)BEGIN(.*?)^END\s*(\w+);"

methodMatches = re.finditer(methodRegex, fContent, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)
        
        for methodMatchNum, methodMatch in enumerate(methodMatches, start=1):
            methodContent=methodMatch.group()
            methodNameFull=methodMatch.group(1)
            methodType=methodMatch.group(2)
            methodName=methodMatch.group(3)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about including the previous line in the regex match, so you can check it for a string, correct?

Comment: You may match what you do not need and match and capture what you need, see [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZIGhKF).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is a negative lookbehind. Try:

```
r"(?<!@Override\s)^\s*((FUNCTION|PROCEDURE)\s+(\w+))(.*?)BEGIN(.*?)^END\s*(\w+);"
```

`(?<!a)b` means look for `b` if you find it, see if there is no `a` before it.

Comment: Yes @Tilman, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help :)